# Fastest way to get the first charachter from a string as a string

Tags: c#, string, performance

I need to get the first letter in a string, and was trying to use `stringValue[0]`. This gave compilation error when I tried to pass it as a parameter to a method, because the method only took `string` as type for that parameter. So I have several options to convert it to `string`:

```
myMethod(stringValue[0].ToString());
myMethod(new String(stringValue[0], 1));
myMethod(stringValue.Substring(0,1));
myMethod("" + stringValue[0]);
```

Which method is the best and fastest regarding performance (thoughts on best practice is also welcome)?

Comment: And what is your test results?

Comment: From Eric Lippert: _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster_ **then race your horses.** http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Proposed Solution

```
string input = "This is a string";
string firstChar = new String(input[0], 1);
```

This is the least number of operations you can do.

1. extract the first `char` by index
2. pass the `char` to the constructor of `String`

[String Constructor (Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### Performance Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringPerf
{
    class Program
    {
        static string firstChar;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "This is a sample string";
            int count = 100000;
            RunPerf("Warmup", 1, () =>
                {
                    PerfContructor(input);
                    PerfSubstring(input);
                    PerfAppend(input);
                });

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            RunPerf("Constructor", count, () => PerfContructor(input));
            Console.WriteLine();

            RunPerf("ToString", count, () => PerfToString(input));
            Console.WriteLine();

            RunPerf("Substring", count, () => PerfSubstring(input));
            Console.WriteLine();

            RunPerf("Append", count, () => PerfAppend(input));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PerfContructor(string input)
        {
            firstChar = new String(input[0], 1);
        }

        static void PerfToString(string input)
        {
            firstChar = input[0].ToString();
        }

        static void PerfSubstring(string input)
        {
            firstChar = input.Substring(0, 1);
        }

        static void PerfAppend(string input)
        {
            firstChar = "" + input[0];
        }

        static void RunPerf(string name, int count, Action action)
        {
            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting perf for {0}. {1} times", name, count));

            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                action();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} completed in {1}", name, sw.Elapsed));
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

```
Starting perf for Warmup. 1 times
Warmup completed in 00:00:00.0003153


Starting perf for Constructor. 9999999 times
Constructor completed in 00:00:00.1961569

Starting perf for ToString. 9999999 times
ToString completed in 00:00:00.2890530

Starting perf for Substring. 9999999 times
Substring completed in 00:00:00.2412256

Starting perf for Append. 9999999 times
Append completed in 00:00:00.3271857
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string firstChar = stringValue.Substring(0, 1);
```

According to the performance part of your question.

> **I wouldn't take performance into consideration here unless it was
>   actually becoming a problem for you** - in which case the only way you'd
>   know would be to have test cases, and then it's easy to just run those
>   test cases for each option and compare the results. I'd expect
>   **Substring to probably be the fastest** here, simply because Substring
>   always ends up creating a string from a single chunk of the original
>   input, whereas Remove has to at least potentially glue together a
>   start chunk and an end chunk.

[Fastest way to remove first char in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222125/fastest-way-to-remove-first-char-in-a-string)

However, if you want to micro-optimize and you really need just the first character, it seems that the string indexer + constructor is a little bit faster than others:

```
string stringValue = "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest";
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
string firstChar;
sw.Start();
for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++)
    firstChar = stringValue.Substring(0, 1);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Substring Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);

sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    firstChar = stringValue[0].ToString();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Char[]-Indexer-ToString Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);

sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    firstChar = new string(stringValue[0],1);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Char[]-Indexer-Constructor Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
```

Result:

```
Substring Elapsed: 00:00:03.0214131
Char[]-Indexer-ToString Elapsed: 00:00:02.1274226
Char[]-Indexer-Constructor Elapsed: 00:00:01.7042839
```

But note that this is really micro-optimization. Readability is more important in most cases. Consider also that you might need to take the first two characters sometime which is easy with `String.Substring`, an array indexer cannot return multiple characters.

Comment: Hey Tim, I think it would be better with an explanation why this gets better performance than others. `;)`

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes, sorry, i noticed too late that he actually wants to know the fastest approach and didn't have the time to add an explanation. But now i have added an answer on a similar question.

Comment: "I'd _expect_ Substring to _probably_ be the fastest here" - seems legit.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If Jon says `SubString` is the fastest, who will argue with it? `:)` +1 from mine.

Comment: @poke There are valuable points at stake here! Serious business.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20216568/109392) and [Gusdor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20216709/109392) I did some testing on my own, and the results made it clear that the fastest methods were

```
stringValue[0].ToString()
```

and

```
new String(stringValue[0], 1)
```

Which of the two is fastest is unclear, as my tests were inconclusive regarding those two. I tried to run them in different order, and it varied which one was the fastest.

I ran it 2E9 times, and these two fastest methods took about 30 seconds.
In comparison, the Substring method was 43 seconds, and the append method was 50 seconds.

Comment: I found that the two methods varied in speed as i increased the test iteration count. I fixed this by assigning to a `static` `string` on each test. I think allocation time was polluting the results.