# C# string.Substring() or string.Remove()

Tags: c#, string, substring

I wonder if it's a better practice to use :

```
var a = b.Substring(6);
```

Or

```
var a = b.Remove(0,6);
```

Which one is more efficient / faster ? Obviously substring has more options you can pick from but nothing that Remove() cant do.. Sorry if it's newbie question, I'm new to C#

Comment: Substring makes more sense in terms of getting a substring from a string heh

Comment: So there's no difference between both ?They do the same work for the same amount of time ?

Comment: Actually, i'm pretty sure Substring will return you a new string with the first 6 characters.. remove will return you a string without the first 6 characters...

Comment: Test it out.  Read the docs.  Don't bother worrying about performance unless you profile it and see that you are spending lots of time in one of the methods.

Comment: Use whatever convey the intent clearly. There shouldn't be much difference between these two, even if there is a difference it would be negligible.

Comment: Efficiency is not a consideration between the two. Their implementation is almost exactly the same. Use the one that conveys the most meaning to you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and positive feedback guys !

Comment: Using ILSpy, `SubString` has a lot more parameter checks than `Remove`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code using reflector, `InternalSubString` is doing only one `wstrcpy` whereas `Remove` is doing two of them. My guess would be the first one(`SubString`) is a tad faster.

Here is the code for the `Remove` method of the string class:

```
public unsafe string Remove(int startIndex, int count)
{
//...
        string text = string.FastAllocateString(num);

        fixed (char* ptr = &this.m_firstChar)
        {
            fixed (char* ptr2 = &text.m_firstChar)
            {
                string.wstrcpy(ptr2, ptr, startIndex);
                string.wstrcpy(ptr2 + (IntPtr)startIndex, ptr + (IntPtr)startIndex + (IntPtr)count, num - startIndex);
            }
        }
}
```

And the code called by the `SubString` method:

```
private unsafe string InternalSubString(int startIndex, int length)
{
    string text = string.FastAllocateString(length);
    fixed (char* ptr = &text.m_firstChar)
    {
        fixed (char* ptr2 = &this.m_firstChar)
        {
            string.wstrcpy(ptr, ptr2 + (IntPtr)startIndex, length);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Is this also true for `string.Remove(int)`?

Comment: @Deantwo `Remove(int)` merely calls `Substring(0, int)`

Answer (score 3):

`Substring` is faster based on this post:

[Fastest way to remove first char in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222125/fastest-way-to-remove-first-char-in-a-string)

"I do check now by call each one about 90000000 and I go the following result:

`Remove`: 06.63 - `TrimStart`: 04.71 - `Substring`: 03.09 so from result `Substring` is the best" - @Amr Badawy

Comment: I wouldn't put too much faith in that benchmark.  It may be true, but we don't truly know how that benchmark was performed.

Answer (score 2):

String instances are immutable - both `Substring()` and `Remove()` will allocate a new string if the return value is different, and will return the same string if it's not, as in this case. `Substring` better reflect the intent, and should be preferred - almost always, it's better to make the code easily understandable than to worry about minute performance differences.