# Delete last specific chars from string

Tags: c#, string, cut

i'm looking for a way to delete specific chars from a string.

The string contains of letters and digits. I want to cut the last or last 2 digits. They are always digits and always the last or last 2 digits. I know what i want to cut.

```
string s = lblTemperature104;
int thermometer 4;
```

In the above case the result should be "lblTemperature10"

Should be looking something like this. Sorry if it's hard to understand but i can't think of another way.

```
public void stringCutter (string s, int toCut){
     s.cutFromBehind(toCut);
```

If you have trouble to understand my question feel free to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the result be "lblTemperature1"? You cut off two characters from the end, so, in my opinion, it should be just "lblTemperature1"

Comment: Hey Eppok, what is with your issue? Please let me know if your problem wasn't solved, otherwise you could pick the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this scenario.

Regular Expression: `(.*)\w{2}`

You can also make use of Remove() which is used for shortening strings and eliminates a range of characters.

```
string str = "lblTemperature104";
str= str.Remove(str.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to delete two last characters from your string.

First, we correct your code, it should be:

```
string s = "lblTemperature104";
int thermometer = 4;
```

The second thing is: There is no difference between letters and numbers when you work with the type [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/).

The third thing is the answer to your question: You actually don't need one extra function `stringCutter`, if you will use the [String.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netcore-3.1) method like so:

```
s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, lng);
```

`lng` here is the number of characters that you want to delete. If you will always delete only 2 characters, you can just write:

```
s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 2);
```

That is just another possible solution. But as  Graham Ormond mentioned, you can do the same with the [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1). According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187988/c-sharp-string-substring-or-string-remove), the `String.Substring` is faster than `String.Remove`.